# Retrieve GPS data from Android Phone

Tags: android, gps, samsung-mobile

To start this off, I do not have an android and have not in years. But, I have been asked by my SO's mother if there is a way to retrieve the location data (e.g. When the phone was at a specific location or locations) and export that into some sort of usable file.

I looked online and was not having much luck, everything I was finding mentioned installing apps to track future data, but I'm looking for past data.

The phone is a Galaxy S4...does anyone have any ideas on what can be done to retrieve this information?

Thanks!

Comment: This question seems to be quite complex. Do you need to find some app for this purpose or do you want to know how to code it?

Comment: @Jerry I'm trying to retrieve this information for them because they are entering a lawsuit and are trying to find more proof that they went to the property when requested to do contracted work.

Answer (score 0):

Sign in to their google account using a browser.
Locate their user settings.
Somewhere in there will be a Location History.
If it has not been disabled it should show the location history of the device.
It'll show a calendar and you can click on the calendar to see what location data is available for each date.

Comment: I was wondering if that would work...I saw a link for something like that within my gmail account, but since I don't use android I didn't have any data.

Comment: This would only work if they have their google account tied to their phone though, correct?

Comment: It would only work if the user was signed into Play Store for the period that location data is required.
I'm not 100% sure but think that location history is enabled by default - so as long as the user was signed in and had not changed the default setting then there should be some location data.